# IE 11: dashed border on selection of an element in tinymce editor

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, tinymce, internet-explorer-11

I am using a custom dropdown in a tinymce editor and it's showing a dashed border on selection of the element.

Any idea how can we get rid of the border without disabling it's functionality?

Comment: Add `outline: 0` to the style of the required element.

Comment: It's not the "focus" dotted border but a tilt-dashed border of a contenteditable element

Comment: @MuradH - did you ever manage to resolve this?